# mysql unique key

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table `items` that holds items that have been select by a user but without a unique or primary key as there no unique records on the table because on every row `userID` and `listID` are not unique (user will surely have more than one item) and `itemID` can be unique/primary as more users might select the same item. What is the correct way to add unique and/or primary key on that table that will make sense?

items table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `userID` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `listID` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `itemID` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

items data:

```
INSERT INTO `items` (`userID`, `listID`, `itemID`, `qty`) VALUES
(12, 277, 44, 2160),
(12, 277, 3683, 13500),
(12, 277, 3689, 2700),
(12 277, 9832, 4320),
(12 277, 9848, 540),
(12, 277, 16272, 81000),
(12, 277, 16273, 81000),
(12, 277, 16274, 243000),
(71, 278, 12066, 4),
(82, 279, 44, 2880),
(82, 279, 3683, 18000),
(82, 279, 3689, 3600),
(82, 279, 9832, 5760);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an index across multiple columns. In this case, I'd recommend having your index across all `ID` columns, so that an item would be unique to a user and a list. This should do the trick:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique ON tbl_name (userID, listID, itemID);
```

Comment: now how can i update a row, is there a way to say `UPDATE unique KEY set something=''`?

Comment: @atno Unfortunately not, no. The unique key only prevents duplicates from being entered. You'd have to do `UPDATE tbl_name SET qty = 123 WHERE userID = 1234 AND listID = 4321 AND itemID = 5678;`. If you want an way of updating a record, look into adding a primary key `ID` as suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Declare an extra "id" column in your table, and use auto-increment.  See e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html.

This column doesn't have any meaning, but it can be used to uniquely reference entries in the table (the whole purpose of the primary key).

Comment: Exactly how does that make the DATA ROW (not the new id column) unique ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column

```
`id` int (20) auto_increment primary key
```

Comment: Exactly how does that make the DATA ROW (not the new `id` column) unique ?

Comment: It doesn't - but that was not the question.